# How to get fail and pass test count of JUNIT test cases

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit4

I written some selenium test case in Java using `junit` framework and running them in a suite.

I need to print all Fail, pass and total test cases count at end of the test suite.

Please help me to get it done

Comment: How are you running the tests?  The Ant and Maven runners automatically print this out at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Add "Assert.fail();" in your catch block

example

try{ ----- your code -----

}catch(Exception e){

Assert.fail();// this is for TestNG

}

Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Create object to ErrorCollercter and add Throwable to ErrorCollecter

*Eg :*

```
 ErrorCollertor errorCollector = new ErrorCollector();

 try
 {
  \\Your code
 }
 Catch(Throwable e)
 {
    errorCollector.add(e);
 }
```

Hope this solves your problem.